# Adding +1 to multiple values in one cell via excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got an excel file with a data source sheet. To be able to parse the data at the next step I need to add 1 to every value and get it into a new sheet. The thing is, that there are multiple values per cell, each separated by comma, and this number is not static. Adding the +1 at a later point is sadly not an option so I need to do this in excel.

```
  Source sheet              Prepared data sheet

| MyValues   |             | MyValues + 1 |
|------------|             |--------------|
| 0,1,2,3    |             |  1,2,3,4     |
| 3          |   ----->    |  4           |
| 2,4,6      |             |  3,5,7       |
| 1          |             |  2           |
```

Comment: If you want to do it through native formulas then you will need helper columns. But through VBA based UDF it can be achieved.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thank you for your comment. As i have to do this native I will probably use helper columns then

Comment: what is the (approximate) maximum number of comma per cell?

Comment: @p._phidot_ approx 1 - 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way doing this (assuming Excel 2016 with `TEXTJOIN()`):

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN($A1))),(COLUMN()-2)*LEN($A1)+1,LEN($A1)))+1,"")
```

- Drag down and sideways (could be 15 columns if need be)

Formula in `G1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B1:E1)
```

- Drag down

You don't need a VBA solution but in your case a UDF could also be a nice way to do this, for example like so:

```
Function AddVal(RNG As Range, VAL As Double) As String

Dim ARR1() As String, ARR2() As String, X As Double
If RNG.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ARR = Split(RNG.Value, ",")
    For X = LBound(ARR) To UBound(ARR)
        ReDim Preserve ARR2(X)
        ARR2(X) = ARR(X) + VAL
    Next X
    If IsEmpty(ARR2) Then
        AddVal = "No hits"
    Else
        AddVal = Join(ARR2, ",")
    End If
Else
    AddVal = "No valid range"
End If

End Function
```

Call through `=AddVal(A1;1)`

You can change the `1` for another number if you want to add more than just 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's helper column based solution. I have assumed data starts from cell `A2` and concatenation formula in cell `B2`. I have considered case of 15 maximum values.

In cell C2, following formula shall be put:

`=IFERROR((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)*99,99))/1)+1,"")`

This shall be copied across (till column Q) and down (till last row of your data).

Then apply concatenation formula as below in cell B2:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(C2," ",D2," ",E2," ",F2," ",G2," ",H2," ",I2," ",J2," ",K2," ",L2," ",M2," ",N2," ",O2," ",P2," ",Q2))," ",",")`

> shall work for Excel Version 2007 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a VBA code (i know that VBA is not tagged) to fulfill this task.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Count As Long, j As Long
    Dim str As Variant, strNew As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            Count = Len(.Range("A" & i).Value) - Len(Replace(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",", ""))
            str = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",")

            If Count > 0 Then

                For j = 0 To Count

                    str(j) = str(j) + 1

                    If .Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
                        .Range("B" & i).Value = str(j)
                    Else
                        .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value & "," & str(j)
                    End If

                Next j

            Else

                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value + 1

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]